# How I can findElement in DOM with Gulp? Its for testing an Electron App

Tags: javascript, dom, gulp, electron

I'm using this code:

```
'use strict';

var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    childProcess  = require('child_process'),
    electron      = require('electron-prebuilt');
var Application = require('spectron').Application;
var assert = require('assert');

gulp.task('run', function () {
    childProcess.spawn(electron, ['./app/main.js'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
    var title=window.document.getElementsByTagName('title');
    console.log('title');
});
```

After that I'm running - gulp run
but I get the following error message:

> Reference Error: window is not defined at Gulp.

Comment: `window` is part of the DOM, of which Node has no knowledge of. You'd have to read and parse the file to retrieve the name.

Comment: using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap/ may be a good place to start

Comment: you can try cheerio: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: I have no experience with electron but I suspect that your electron app is using a DOM or window object and that there is some way of querying the app to get a reference to it.

Otherwise, as others have said,  window is usually provided by a browser and Node.js doesn't provide such an object and even if it did, it would not be the one you needed to access